# How to find $y(x,z)$ from the given set of data?

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, exponential-function, relations, regression

I have the following set of data:

[image]

$x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_m$ are increasing in arithmetical  progression.

$y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots,y_n$ are increasing in arithmetical  progression.

$z(x_i,y_1),z(x_i,y_2),z(x_i,y_3),\dots,z(x_i,y_n)$ are exponentially increasing for $i=1,2,3,\dots,m$.

$z(x_1,y_i),z(x_2,y_i),z(x_3,y_i),\dots,z(x_m,y_i)$ are exponentially decreasing for $i=1,2,3,\dots,n$.

All values in the table are positive.

The required is to find the value of $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$, [i.e. $y(x,z)$].

> How to find $y(x,z)$ from the given set of data?

---

Consider the following example:

The data set is:

[image]

Say we need to find the value of $y$ when $x=172$ and $z=3.1527$. Clearly, from the table, we can find that $y(172,3.1527)=25.50$.

What if we want to find $y(150,3.1729)$? which is not in the table

The answer is $y(x,z)=x(-1+\ln(z))$, so $y(150,3.1729)=150(-1+\ln(3.1729))=23.1969$

I actually know the expression $\boxed{y(x,z)=x(-1+\ln(z))}$ because I made this example to demonstrate my problem.

What if we do not know that relation, how should we obtain it?

---

This problem is related to my research in the chemical laboratory, where the values of $x$'s are the speeds of the centrifuge (rpm), the values of $y$'s are the volumes of the samples (mL), and the values of $z$'s are the length in (mm) of the extracted liquid in the pictures that are taken by a camera.

---

Regardless of my research, and regardless of the units (rpm, mL, mm), can we generalise a method?

---

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Is something like [this](http://evoq-eval.siam.org/Portals/0/Publications/SIURO/Vol1_Issue1/A_Simple_Expression_for_Multivariate.pdf?ver=2018-03-30-130233-050) what you're looking for?

Comment: @saulspatz almost like Example 2 in the provided link. But the form of $z_i$ is provided in that example, while for my problem the form of $z$ is not known well, it is known that it is exponential growth (when going down), and exponential decay (when going right).

Comment: Let's say there's a relation between two cells $y_i$, $y_{i+1}$ in the form $y=f(x)$; and you say that $f$ is exponential. I ask "is that $f$ the same for all cells in a column?" If the answer is yes then you can do a regresion for that function with all cells in that column. If not, that's another deal.

Comment: @Ripi2 The answer is yes, $f$ the same for all cells in a column.

Answer (score 3):

HINT.

Formally, is described the model
$$z(x,y) = e^{a+bx+cy},$$
or
$$\ln z = a+bx+cy,\tag1$$
where $b<0, c>0,$
$$x_i=12+2.25i,\quad y_i= 100 + 24j.$$

The table data model is
$$z_{i,j} = e^{\large \frac xy+1}\tag2$$

[image: Table data]

Assuming the discrepancy in the form of
$$d(a,b,c) = \sum w_{i,j}(\ln z_{i,j} - a - bx_i - Cy_j)^2,\tag3$$
where $w_{ij}$ is the arbitrary matrix of weights,

one can get the point (A,B,C), which provides $\min d(a,b,c)$ in accordance with the described model.

This point is the stationary point of $d(a,b,c).$

So $\operatorname{grad} d(A,B,C) = 0,$ or
\begin{cases}
\sum w_{i,j}\ (\ln z_{i,j} - A - Bx_i - Cy_j)=0\\
\sum w_{i,j}\ i\ (\ln z_{i,j} - A - Bx_i - Cy_j)=0\\
\sum w_{i,j}\ j\ (\ln z_{i,j}  - A - Bx_i - Cy_j) = 0.\tag4
\end{cases}

This leads to the linear system
\begin{cases} 
S_{00}A + S_{10} B + S_{01}C = R_{00}\\
S_{10}A + S_{20} B + S_{11}C = R_{10}\\
S_{01}A + S_{11} B + S_{02}C = R_{01},\tag5
\end{cases}

where 
$$S_{kl} = \sum w_{ij}x_i^k y_j^l,\quad R_{kl} = \sum w_{ij} x_i^k j^l \ln z_{ij}.\tag6$$

Using weight array $w=1$ gives

[image: w=1]

and looks unusable. This situation is happened, because the data table does not correspond to the model.

However, applying of the weight array in the form of
$$w_{ij}=e^{-\left(\Large\frac{5(x_i-150)}{24}\right)^2-\left(\Large\frac{2(y_j-23.25)}{2.25}\right)^2}$$

localizes the model and gives

[image: solution w<>1]

So the estimation is
$$Y = \dfrac{\ln z -A-Bx}C 
\approx \dfrac{\ln z - 1.13517\ 52307 + 0.00091\ 33448x}{0.00675\ 67568}, \tag7$$

and the result

[image: y(150,3.1729)]

looks suitable.

Note that the constants "2" and "5" in the $w$ formula were obtained empirically,
with the goal of the good approximation of the table data near of the expected point. If the table data model corresponds with the given model better, then these constants can be decreased or $w=1$ can be used.

Comment: I think this solution is too mathematic. Perfect if the whole data fit exactly in a formula. But if values come from a sensor, you have to deal with errors, noise, and other issues. And if there are some "hidden vars" that change the model between two rows/cols then this solution gets completely invalid.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks for the comment, fixed. Really, the table data model $(2)$ does not correspond with the used mathematic model $(1)$, and now this situation can be understood from my answer.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Thanks dear. I am still trying to understand your answer. I do not know about "matrix of weights". I am reading about it in some websites. But sill I can not see any generalisation in your answer (I mean, I am not focusing in the provided example), and I can not see a function $(y=f(x,z))$. No worries, bounties will be gained when I see how can we find such function (for any set of data, that has the same given conditions :)  . Your work is really appreciated, now I am counting to understand.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Thank you for the comment, you are welcome! The weight array allows to use more significant data and to ignore less significant. In this case, the greatest weights have the points near the expected point. Also, are detalized both the function $y=f(x,z)$ and the calculation process. Good luck!

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Waitting for the comments. How this algorithm works in the practical tasks?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Ok dear, I will let you know tomorrow what is the practical task. Now it is 11:10 pm in my country, tomorrow morning when I go to the lab, I will try provide some pictures that clarify my problem.

Answer (score 3):

*General Premise*

A *proper* regression analysis of a set of data points (2D,3D,..) shall be done with due regard
to the underlying phisical phenomena and statistical considerations that generated the data.

The physical model is the only hint that may suggest a proper relation (mathematical function) among the data.
The statistical and phisical considerations are to determine what "deviations" the data may have from the assumed model.
This fundamentally means to assess which variables are (relatively) "exact" and which prone to error, if the errors may be assumed to be 
independent, non-systematic, constant-variable variance (homo/hetero- scedastic).

Omitting this step translates into an arbitrary regression.
Take for instance a linear 2D regression: you may have that the $x_k$ are "precise", while the $y_k$ are prone to error, or viceversa.
You may also have errors in both, in which case you should apply [Total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares)
regression, for instance.
The result in the three cases are usually different.

*Your case*

Coming to your case, and dealing with it very concisely, you need first to assess the following questions:
 a) which of the $3$ variables are "exact"/"erroneous"?
 b) may the errors be reasonably assumed to be non systematic, not related and not cross-related ?
 c) are the variables hetero/homo-scedastic ?

Now, if the answer to a) is $x,y$ exact and $z$ erroneous, than you shall apply a 2D regression to your data, get
$z(x,y)$ according to your presumed model, solve it to extract $y(z,x)$.

Which regression analysis to apply depends on the answer to b). If it is a full yes, then you can apply simple least squares.

The answer to c) is much important in your case, when $z(x,y)$ is assumed to be an exponential function.
In fact, if the **relative errors** in $z$ may be assumed to be i.i.d., then  $\log(z)$ is homo-scedastic and you can apply linear regression 
on that. Otherwise you cannot reliably do that.

Finally, if instead the answer to a) is that $y$ is erroneous, while $x,z$ are relatively exact, then practically you have just to transform your table
into a $y(x,z)$, by listing all the available $z_k$ in the top row, and filling with the corresponding $y(x,z)$.
After that the process is same as the above.

A final note about your closing question

> What if we do not know that relation, how should we obtain it?

As told above, only the underlying physical process can suggest a model to adopt, which means a mathematical relation
among the observable data (linear, polynomial, exponential, ...) and which ( of the most important) parameters (the unknowns in the regression) are
to be included in it. A typical example is the intercept, or some other point which is phisically obvious that the model shall include.
And what about the range of validity of the regression?  Only  a careful consideration of the process jointly with the purposed use of the model can 
asses that.
A precious help in deciding the model is provided by a [scatterplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot), but that shall be only and remain just an aid.

Answer (score 2):

An exponential function is kind of $f(x)=z=a+b·e^{c·x}$

First compute all regresions, one for each row.

For example, the row $y=21.00$ results in $z=2.89657+1.73346\cdot e^{(-0.0134048\cdot x)}$

And the row $y=23.25$ results in $z=2.91707+1.96536\cdot e^{(-0.135084\cdot x)}$

Next calculate the z values for given $x=150$ for all rows. In the example $z(21.00, 150) = 3.12866683809$ and $z(23.25, 150) = 3.17615876206$

Do another exponential regression $f(y_{150})=z_{150}=A+B·e^{C·y}$ with the "y" values of the table and those "150" column "z" calculated values.

And now get $y= \frac{1}{C} ln\frac{(z-A)}{B}$

Comment: Dear sir, what I understood from your answer is that for any given values ($x$ and $z$) we have a different equations to find the value of $y$, so for $y(24.73,142)$ I will find an equation, and for $y(26.3,199)$ I will find another equation. Can not we find one evaluate (estimate) $y$ using only one equation, that is $y=f(x,z)$?

Comment: If you know in advance that all vales come from an unique function, you can try a 3D regression. Search for "multiple regression".

Answer (score 0):

If I had to work such a problem, I should use a bilinear model based on the $p > 4$ surrounding closest data points in the table.

This means that 
$$\log(z)=a+ b x+c y+d x y$$ This is a simple task to achieve in the least-square sense and, when done, extract
$$y=\frac{\log (z)-a-b x}{c+d x}$$

I did not use (on purpose) the fact that the $x$'s and the $y$'s are in arithmetic progressions. But this will help a lot to find the surrounding points in the table.

Answer (score 0):

When the dynamics of the process that generated the data is known, then a model that has a specific structure can be proposed. This is the case of many processes in mechanics, chemical kinetics, etc. When those dynamics are unknown, the identification process is transformed into a divinatory procedure. There are also the so called black box procedures involving neural nets, etc. In this the case we adopted a smooth model inspired by the data quality.

After trying different algebraically simple models, the best one according to our settings is

$$
z(x,y) =\frac{a_1 x}{x-a_2}+\frac{b_1 y}{x-b_2}+c_1
$$

regarding the furnished data, the parametric values are

$$
\cases{
c_1=2.78608\\
a_1=-0.0596403\\
a_2=58.6578\\
b_1=2.7319\\
b_2=20.0174}
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which gives those results

```
f[X_, Y_] := Exp[a1 X + b1 Y + c1]
f[X_, Y_] := Exp[a1 /(X - a2) + b1/(Y - b2) + c1]
f[X_, Y_] := Exp[a1 /(X - a2) + b1 Y + c1]
f[X_, Y_] := a1 X/(X - a2) + b1 Y/(X - b2) + c1
For[i = 1; error2 = 0, i <= Length[X], i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= Length[Y], j++,
  error2 = error2 + (wrds2[[j, i]] - f[X[[i]], Y[[j]]])^2
  ]
]
sol = NMinimize[error2, {c1, a1, a2, b1, b2},Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

Follows the table level surfaces plot and the data points in red and cuts along the $y$ axis on $z(x,y)$

[image]

and the adjusted formula

$$
y = \frac{(x-b_2) (x (a_1+c_1-z)-a_2 (z-c_1))}{b_1(x-a_2)}
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the two "exponentially increasing", resp., "exponentially decreasing" claims are meant to be exact the whole problem reduces to the simple algebraic problem of determining a small number of parameter values.

The two claims can be written out in the following form: There are functions $a(x)$, $b(y)$, $\lambda(x)$, $\mu(y)$ such that we have identically in $x$ and $y$ the relations
$$z(x,y)=e^{a(x)}\>e^{\lambda(x) y},\qquad z(x,y)=e^{b(y)}\>e^{-\mu(y)x}\ ,$$
which implies
$$a(x)+\lambda(x) y=b(y)-\mu(y) x\ .\tag{1}$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ gives
$$a'(x)+\lambda'(x)y=-\mu(y),\qquad \lambda(x)=b'(y)-\mu'(y) x\ .\tag{2}$$
Plugging $-\mu(y)$ and $\lambda(x)$ from $(2)$ into $(1)$ leads to
$$\bigl(a(x)-xa'(x)\bigr)-\bigl(b(y)-y b'(y)\bigr)\equiv\bigl(\lambda'(x)+\mu'(y)\bigr)xy\ .$$
This implies $\lambda'(x)+\mu'(y)\equiv0$, or
$$\lambda(x)=\lambda_0+\tau x,\qquad \mu(y)=\mu_0-\tau y$$
for constants $\lambda_0$, $\mu_0$, $\tau$. Furthermore we have
$$a(x)-xa'(x)=b(y)-y b'(y)=c$$
for a certain $c$, and this implies
$$a(x)=\alpha x+c,\qquad b(x)=\beta x+c$$
for certain $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

It remains to determine the constants $\lambda_0$, $\mu_0$, $\tau$, $c$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ from the given data.